# Difference media controller vs. transport controls Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I am trying to understand what each of these two Android constructs actually are and of course how they work, especially the transport controls, when dealing with the MediaPlayer and the MediaSession classes.

From the official documentation about the MediaSession, it

> Allows interaction with media controllers, volume keys, media buttons, and transport controls.

As far as I understood, the media buttons refers to actual physical buttons on a device (if existent) or for ex. on a Bluetooth headset. Volume keys are obvious.

When comes to the media *controllers* I think I managed to figure out that it refers to a particular View, the FrameView that has buttons for play/pause as well as skip next/previous etc. But what exactly are the *transport controls* then, where can/should they be used and how are they implemented in code?

Thank you in advance for any answers!

Comment: Transport controls the media player, media controller is for intercepting the media buttons. Media controller event -> transport control action

Comment: The reason they are different is the fact that you can use the transport controller from order object within your app via media session object

Comment: @pantos27 thank you for that, would you be able to point me to any sort of code snippet (even the most basic actions) that would show me to see the usage of both? If not, it's okay, thank you anyway for the reply

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ianhanniballake/15dce0b233b4f4b23ef8

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/playback/PlaybackManager.java#L150

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference for myself or others, the **MediaPlayer** is essentially like the internal mechanism of a stereo player, and directly controls the sound playback, "internally". You do have functions on it, like play(), pause(), skipToNext(), etc.

When you want to create a music application, you'd normally implement a client-service model, with the app interface being your client (in the main UI thread), and the service will play the music (also in the background). What Google did was implement a client-service model specifically for music and video, the **MediaSession(Compat)**. It has its own type of service, session states (when you want to have Notifications, Android Wear or Auto, so they know if the app is playing or paused, can get the track information and album image, etc. so that everything is well synchronized on all these platforms), and the ***MediaController*** and its callbacks that need to be implemented for different functionality.

One of its options is to **getTransportControls()**, which essentially are a high-level representation of what happens when you'd press the play(), pause(), etc. buttons on that stereo player mentioned earlier. For each of these you @Override their respective onPlay(), onPause() callback methods to do the exact functionality you want on that *MediaPlayer* object that controls your music. In here is where you'd then call the MediaPlayer.play() functions, as well as setting the playback state of MediaSession, possibly update the notification, etc.

As for the others, volume keys are indeed the volume keys, and the *Media Buttons* are indeed physical buttons you might have (Bluetooth headset, earphones with playback buttons, etc.) that you can set up your app so it recognizes and makes use of them.

For whoever is interested to see this better in action, below is the repo of my app project. Although far from a fully-featured, bug-free app, it does implement the MediaSession and the Service, plus notifications and MediaButton controls pretty much perfectly.

https://github.com/RockBoyEmy/GESMediaPlayer

thanks also to @pantos27 for his help